# Binding to ViewModel and CodeBehind a reusable UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, prism

I have a *usercontrolX* that i created to use it more than one time in a *PageX* view.
it contains a button and a textbox , and i want to bind the textbox to a property in **PageXModelView** and the button should do something in my **usercontrolXModelView**.

The problem is when i add the *usercontrolX* to the view i can bind it to the PageX property  only if i bind the textboxt to a **usercontrolX behind code** and not in the **usercontrolXModelView** and for the button it works only if I bind it to a property in **usercontrolXModelView** , So is there a solution to bind the *usercontrolX*  to the **usercontrolXModelView** and the **usercontrolX behind code**

- Here is project :

Views : UserControlX , Page , MainWindow

ModelViews : UserControlXMV, PageMV , MainWindowMV

```
< UserControl x:Class="APPia.Views.Usercontrolx" mc:Ignorable="d"  Name="Usercontrolx">
    < Button Name="B1" Content="Button" Command="{Binding UpdateCommandx, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    < Label Name="L21" Content="{Binding Path=propX,ElementName=Usercontrolx}"/>
</UserControl>


<UserControl x:Name="PageX"">
<Grid>
<TextBox Text="{Binding persowxn.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<UserControlX x:Name="Contx1" propX="{Binding persowxn.Name}" />
<UserControlX x:Name="Contx2" propX="{Binding persowxn.Surname}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: If this is just a button and label then putting them in a usercontrol looks like it's just complicating things here. Maybe we could help you better if you explain more about how this is to work.  For example it could well be that templating a collection out would suit better.

Answer (score 1):

In your user control's code-behind, add a dependency property. Then bind the user control's label's content to that dependency property. And then bind the user control's dependency property to your page's view model's property.

Same for the button inside the user control...